# How to use Spring Dependency Injection with class inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a parent class called BaseService and I have other services that inherit from BaseService as they all need those methods to do their jobs.  As always the methods of the superclass are available inside the subclass...  However, when I use @Autowired DI to inject the subclass I am not able to use the methods defined by the parent class, I am only able to use what is defined separately in the subclass.  How can I inject the subclass and have it properly instantiate the subclass such that the methods of the parent class are available to me?

Ex. Parent Class

```
@Service
public class BaseService{

  public BooleanExpression combineBools(Predicate predicate, BooleanExpression bool){
     BooleanExpression result = runupBool.and(predicate);
     return result;
  }
}
```

Ex. Child Class

```
    @Service
    public class EqServiceImpl extends BaseService implements EqService{
     public EqServiceImpl(){
       super();
     }

     @Override
     public Iterable getAllData(Map<String, String> params, Predicate predicate) {
       // Some Method Specific to Child Class
     }
    }
```

Ex. Controller

```
    @RestController
    public class EqController {

      @Autowired
      EqService eqService

      ...
    }
```

If I wanted to access the method `eqService.combineBools()` inside the controller I am unable to.  Why is this?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're stating.

Comment: How are the methods in the parent class defined, and how are you calling them? Are you able to instantiate these classes manually and get the desired result?

Comment: @BillMan I am able to instantiate the classes manually but would prefer DI instead.  Please see the edited question above to give a better sense of what I am talking about.

Comment: Does your eqService even define the `combineBools` method? THis isn't a spring issue.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe it doesn't need to define it.  It inherits it.

Comment: EqServiceImpl extends BaseService implements EqService. Where does EqService implement the BaseService which has the `combineBools` method defined? Again. This is a java problem. EqService _has_ to define the combineBools method, or you need to cast your class to `BaseService`

Comment: @DarrenForsythe you are most correct.  I should have given more attention to what type I was instantiating with.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

As DarrenForsythe pointed out I am instantiating with EqService as the type so it would not have all of the methods of the BaseService since it does not extend that class, rather it is the EqServiceImpl that extends that class.  Therefore I would need the type to be EqServiceImpl.  Without making some other changes @Autowired is not the best choice for DI here.